# update each row in a procedure

Tags: sql, procedure

I have the following data in a table TABLE1

DOCUMENT ------ FIELD1
12345
23456
34567
45678
98765

i have the following data in a view VIEW1

DOCUMENT ---- BUS
12345 ------------ 5
23456 ------------ 6
34567 ------------ 8
45678 ------------ 12
98765 ------------ 14

What i would like to do is update each row

if (table1.document = view1.document)
then
table1.field1 = view1.bus

Any insight will help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done using plain SQL, no procedures required:

```
UPDATE table1 SET field1 = (SELECT bus FROM view1 WHERE table1.document = view1.document)
```

Or, if your database allows it:

```
UPDATE (select table1.field1, view1.bus FROM table1 JOIN view1 ON table1.document = view1.document) SET table1.field1 = view1.bus
```

Comment: Thank you.  I've tried 'for each row', select into, different update clauses. nothing worked.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As Dan said, but in MS SQL Server I find this styling easier to read:

```
UPDATE U
SET U.field1 = V.bus 
FROM table1 AS U
    JOIN view1 AS V
       ON V.document = U.document
```

Note that if VIEW1 could have multiple rows for a given TABLE1 row [DOCUMENT] value then the [BUS] value choosen to update TABLE1 will be random, within the matching set. (If this is the case the query could be modified to choose MAX / MIN / etc.)

I would refine this query to NOT update any rows that already matched the BUS value, which will make it faster if it is rerun and thus some values already exist in TABLE1

```
UPDATE U
SET U.field1 = V.bus 
FROM table1 AS U
    JOIN view1 AS V
       ON V.document = U.document
WHERE    U.field1 = V.bus
      OR (U.field1 IS NOT NULL AND V.bus IS NULL)
      OR (U.field1 IS NULL AND V.bus IS NOT NULL)
```

you can leave out the NULL / NOT NULL tests if the field is defined as not allowing NULLs.

Comment: This is invalid syntax in sql server. Did you test it? check the correct one here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21000449/4795214  (in short: you cannot use alias U in the first line, you MUST repeat `table1`)

Comment: That is not correct, did you test it?. You can definitely do UPDATE AliasName SET ... FROM MyTable AS AliasName in SQL Server - link to the DOCs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I tested it. Please edit your answer so that I can remove my downvote :)

Comment: Either I am misunderstanding your description, or you are incorrect.  Here is an example of an UPDATE using an alias, as per the DOCs
CREATE TABLE table1 (ID int, field1 varchar(10)); INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1, 'xxx'); UPDATE U SET field1 = 'YYY' FROM table1 AS U; SELECT * FROM table1;

Comment: I mean by my previous comment you are right and I was wrong :) and I ask you to edit your answer so that I can remove my stupid downvote :)

Comment: Ah - now I understand, sorry.  I didn't realise I had to make a (NULL) edit to my post to allow you to change your vote ... that doesn't seem very smart, surely if you change your mind then you should be allow to change your vote!  I've edited my answer :)

Comment: This is really not good. I think we need to submit that issue in stackoverflow meta