# In SQL how do you update each row of the table by finding all rows that are equal for a column, then set another column equal to eachother

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

So basically this would be the psuedo code, but I don't know how to do this in SQL, please help.

```
for each row in table1{
    loop through each row in table 2 {
        if table1's row.column 1 = table2's row.column 2 for this row {
            set table1's row.col2 = table2's row.col2
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Okay let me be more specific. We are basically switching from hibernate sequence as ids to using guids for the id column. I'm trying to update the foreign keys associated by making a temp of the previous foreign key column and then matching the temporary columns to update the actual columns.

suppose table one had id's and table two had a column for those ids to use as foreign keys. I wanna use the previous values in table 2 to match with the rows in table 1 and set the key values in table 2 to match the new guid of table 1.

so table 2 may have multiple rows of duplicate id's but table 1 will never have duplicates. If that makes any sense.

Comment: crucial part of this problem is each row from table 1 needs to find a matching row from table 2.

Comment: What should happen if there are more than one matching row in table 2? What should happen if there's no matching row?

Comment: Start thinking in sets and **do not** loop through each row in a table.

Comment: if there are no matching rows then an error is okay, there should be no multiple matching rows. Basically what happened is we converted a sequence column to use guids so there should be no duplicates

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In SQL Server you can do something like:

```
UPDATE Table_1
SET Column_2 = t2.Column_2
FROM Table_1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table_2 AS t2 ON t2.Column_1 = t1.Column_1
```

or something like

```
UPDATE Table_1
SET Column_2 = ( 
    SELECT t2.Column_2
    FROM Table_2 AS t2
    WHERE t2.Column_1 = Table_1.Column_1
)
```

Of course if you have multiple rows in Table_2, you will get an error....

Comment: Your "of course" only applies to the second form of the query. In the first form, it doesn't raise an error. It silently uses *one* of the values and ignores the other. That's why I've asked the OP how/if we need to handle such situations.

Comment: Or even select into a CTE and update the CTE, easier to understand for a lot of people :)

Comment: Depending on the needs the "of course" can be handled with a `MIN/MAX()` or `LIMIT 1` or `TOP 1`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that someone trying to think SQL in "loop" terms will find any of the answers easy to understand, even a CTE... Hopefully no one will suggest him a CURSOR statement...

Comment: yeah I am very novice in SQL and since I been doing programming for years habits is hard to break :/

Comment: I'm not too sure yet but I think the second part of this answer solves my problem! THANK YOU ALL SO MUCH!

EDIT: yep just tried it, it's exactly what i needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The basics of it is:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET col2 =
     (select col2 FROM Table2 where Table2.column2 = Table1.column1)
```

But that may not do exactly what you need if there's not a 1-1 correspondence between rows in the two tables - and hence my current comment below your question:

> What should happen if there are more than one matching row in table 2? What should happen if there's no matching row?

Answer (score 1):

I think the below query would exactly satisfy the pseudo code
`UPDATE table1 SET column2 = table2.column2 from table2 where table1.column1 = table2.column2;`

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify an issue I had with other DBMS's like FIREBIRD for example, in the subquery, you need to select with a distinct in the clause, like this:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET col2 =
 (select DISTINCT col2 FROM Table2 where Table2.column2 = Table1.column1)
```

Otherwise you'll be getting this error `Multiple rows in singleton select`.
Which makes sense, since you can't select and return multiple rows to update only one row, using `DISTINCT`, the query will loop through each row separately while updating it.